# Chrome dev tools: Object property auto-completion in Console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Firebug supports object property auto-completion in Console. 
Whenever we type an object in console as in the screenshot, it starts showing all the properties available for that object and it helps in selecting the required property easily.

But, see this feature is missing in chrome dev tools. Dose chrome dev tools support auto-completion of object properties or any workaround to achieve this?

[image: Object property auto-completion in Firebug]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome performs autocompletion if you follow `object.property` format instead of `object['property']`.

Comment: Thanks. Am used to square bracket notation for accessing properties. But, will use dotted notation for getting auto-completion.